# MapPageRoute is throwing error in Global.asax

Tags: c#, url-rewriting, url-routing, global-asax

I am trying to re-write the URL for SEO friendly pattern. Best way is to remove the file extension. I visited some tutorial where the use of Global.asax file was suggested.

I am using .net framework 3.5 and in which I am getting the below error:

Error   CS1061  'RouteCollection' does not contain a definition for 'MapPageRoute' and no accessible extension method 'MapPageRoute' accepting a first argument of type 'RouteCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am using the code below in the global.asax file for routing.

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
<script runat="server">
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("Customers", "Customers", "~/Customers.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("CustomerDetails", "Customers/{CustomerId}", "~/CustomerDetails.aspx");

    }
</script>
```

Please help how to fix this issue.

I have checked the reference of system.web.routing. Its correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Although `.MapPageRoute()` exists within the `System.Web.Routing` namespace this only applies to .NET versions `4.0` and higher. If you take a look at the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.routing.routecollection.mappageroute?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to) you'll see a heading at the bottom of the page called "Applies To".

This section should appear on all pages, so whenever you encounter an `Error CS1061` it's worth checking the docs to see if it exists for the version of .NET you're targeting.

To resolve this, the easiest thing to do would be to upgrade your project from .NET 3.5 to 4.0, or (if this is not appropriate for your situation) find another way to do your URL rewriting.